# Required positional argument: 'self', when loading from list

Tags: python, arrays, list, object, oop

Im trying to load the data from a list in python where, I save the data in a list:

```py
class Region(object):

    def __init__(self, cities: list[CitiySalah], label: str):
        self.cities = cities
        self.label = label

    def toMap(self) -> dict:
        map = self.__dict__
        r = [{}]
        for x in self.cities:
            r.append(x.toMap())
        map["cities"] = r
        return map
```

and the one that loads the data is:

```py
def startLoading() -> list[Region]:

.......
    for select in selects:
        if select.has_attr("name") and select['name'] == "ville":
            groups = select.find_all('optgroup')
            for group in groups:
                lable = group['label']
                allR = {"lable": lable}
                cities = [CitiySalah]
                for option in group:
                    try:
                        # the city
                        if(option.has_attr('value')):
                            value = option['value']
                            city = str(option).split('<')[1].split('>')[1]
                            id = str(option).split('<')[1].split(
                                '?ville=')[1].split('"')[0]
                            dataUrl = url+"?ville="+id
                            data = MySalah(getSalahHour(dataUrl))
                            R = CitiySalah(argu={"value": value,
                                                 "city": city,
                                                 "dataUrl": dataUrl,
                                                 "id": id, }, data=data)
                            # print(R.toMap())
                            cities.append(R)
                    except:
                        pass
                # allR['cities'] = cities
                res.append(Region(label=lable, cities=cities))
    return res
```

and when I'm trying to call the function by:

```py
def getDataForDatabase():
    listR = [{}]
    data = startLoading()
    for x in data:
        listR.append(x.toMap())
    return listR
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nimr/ServerApps/ScrappingProject/Salah/Functions.py", line 108, in <module>
    print(getDataForDatabase())
  File "/home/nimr/ServerApps/ScrappingProject/Salah/Functions.py", line 104, in getDataForDatabase
    listR.append(x.toMap())
TypeError: toMap() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I have tried, I'm still new in python as I'm from c++ family, and I got stuck here,
I need to save the data in a list and convert them into Map, so I can save them in the database (NoSQL).

and as for the rest of models they are working correct, I don't know why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Print(x) and see if it’s a Region object

Comment: As an aside, `map = self.__dict__` why are you doing this? That seems... inadvisable.

Comment: i don't understand why you create list with empty set - `listR = [{}]` and `r = [{}]` ? It seems this `set` `{}` will be never used but it can make problem when you expect list only with instaces of `Region`. Why not `listR = []` and `r = []`

Comment: I made the ```listR = [{}]```, to understand the input, this how I used to init a list of Map objects in other languages, is it wrong in python, and I made ```map = self.__dict__```, to get the dictionary of my current object and change another object which is a ```CitiySalah``` in my case to a dictionary